# I prompted error messages when I started Tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat

Ignoring bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userMapper' defined in file：

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory': : Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [config/spring-mybatis.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\me-webapps\yftj-web\WEB-INF\classes\cn\scyf\hmss\mapper\OrderMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.

Comment: The error is very clear: "Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\...". Have you checked that mapping file?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not mapping file

Comment: unfortunately, the classloader currently points toward that file. There is not enough information to guess where the error comes from, you may need to show other config files. A good example would be this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124796/error-parsing-mapper-xml-cause-java-lang-nullpointerexception

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I've regenerated the mapping file and entity.